# is there a way to more elegantly manipulate Date objects in this example?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jstl

I have this problem where I'm asking a user to input a date I'm using  JQueryUI for it which formats it to a MM/dd/yyyy string. However, my form object takes in Dates so I want to be able to send this string as a Date through the form.

```
<input type="text" class="points datepicker" name="evaluationYear2"
                           value="${nomination.evaluationYear2}"
                           <c:if test="${mode==cons.READ_ONLY}">disabled</c:if> />
```

I need to send `evaluationYear2` as a Date object (instead of a string). How can I do this? Furthermore `nomination` is a **form object** I'm receiving due to my controller method and is there just for review (i.e. when errors show up so it refreshes with the previous info) and obviously this sends it back as a Date Object also so I need that formatted to MM/dd/yyyy as well.

I've tried this to no avail, obviously because it doesn't make any sense coding wise:

```
<input type="text" class="points datepicker" name="evaluationYear2t"
                           value="${nomination.evaluationYear2}"
                           <c:if test="${mode==cons.READ_ONLY}">disabled</c:if> />

 <fmt:parseDate var="evaluationYear2" value="${evaluationYear2t}" type="DATE" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

Comment: Date parsing should take place in controller side. I.e. in Spring MVC side.

Comment: so i should send the date as a string? But then I can't do validation like using the `@Past` annotation in my form because my submit method takes in a `@Valid form object`. Does @Past maybe work with strings? I'm obviously new to this, sorry. What I'm trying to say is that it has to be done between the submitting and the controller method in order to be validated. Maybe using javascript?

Comment: I'd read through http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

The solution I'm using in my application is implement a Converter and use the Converter and Convert annotations to automatically convert back and forth between String's and DateTime's. It looks like there may be better ways to do this according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It will be best, if you send Date as string, or even timestamp.
You can use `@InitBinder` here:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }
```

Or, you can get the parameter directly from request by using getParameter() from `HttpServletRequest` object and do validation by hands.